# Parameter action<T> to an instance

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I want to extract an instance from my parameter inside my car class and in my code I have something like:

```
class Car
{
    static Car MakeCustomCarWithColor(string color)
    {
        return new Car(c => c.Color = color);
    }
    public Car(Action<ICustomizeCar> customization)
    {
        //here I want to access the values from customization
        // how to convert Action<ICustomizeCar>
        ICustomizeCar myCustom = ?????????????????????????????;
        // It prints the color passed from Builder class            
        Console.WriteLine(myCustom.Color);
    }

    public interface ICustomizeCar
    {
        string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your `Car(Action<ICustomizeCar>)` constructor and any fields related to this question that you have. Your code right now would not compile.

Comment: You won't be able to extract this information from `Action<T>`, you'll probably want to use `Expression<Action<T>>` and parse the expression tree

Comment: And what's wrong with `new Car { Color = color }`? It looks like you are over engineering your design.

Comment: And what implements ICustomizeCar?

Comment: It's just a nutshell sample. I wanna use something like var myCar = new Car(c => c.Color = "BLUE");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my mind your Car class should implements ICustomizeCar interface, so you can send this pointer to the action.

```
class Car
  : ICustomizeCar
{
   ICustomizeCar::Color {get;set;} 

    static Car MakeCustomCarWithColor(string color)
    {
        return new Car(c => c.Color = color);
    }
    public Car(Action<ICustomizeCar> customization)
    {
        customization(this);
        Console.WriteLine(myCustom.Color);
    }

    public interface ICustomizeCar
    {
        string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```